# How to determine android device resolution is small, medium, or large

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app and I need to identify the android screen/resolution is whether small, medium or large to adjust some content with the available space. For example, some labels (single line) are getting truncated in smaller devices. So I could make some adjustments if the resolution is smaller or not.

In iOS, when iPhone screen getting bigger, the resolution is also getting increased so it's easy to identify smaller resolution devices in iOS. But in android, this seems hard.

Android device resolution can be taken from

```
var resolutionH = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
var resolutionW = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
```

For testing, I have created the following emulators and run the app in them. Here's my result whether a label getting truncated or not.

```
Resolution  Density  Result
---------------------------
2560x1440   560      OK
1920x1080   400      OK

1280x720    320      Truncated
1280x720    280      OK
1280x720    240      OK
800x480     240      Truncated
800x480     160      OK
```

The problem here is a device with higher resolution and lower DPI won't cause any problem. Like a device with 1280x720 resolution and 240 DPI (or 280 DPI). Since there are tons of Android devices are available with different resolutions and densities this problem seems harder.

Is there a better way to categorized android devices (small, medium, and large)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason where a label's text getting truncated (in my case) or an element doesn't get enough space in a particular device is, the actual pixel calculation for an element using the density (dpi/ppi) and the density bucket that screen falls into. This article gives a good idea about calculating the physical size of an element for different display densities.

After some exhausting research, I was able to categorize the device screen by taking the combination of screen width pixels and density. (I got the data from Android developer website [Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) and [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html))

I have categorized the screen width pixels into 4 categories and then calculated the screen size for each display density using following formula:

```
sqrt((widthPixels x widthPixels) + (heightPixels x heightPixels)) / density
```

[image: screen configurations]

Then I have searched in the [GSMArena](https://gsmarena.com) to find devices with the screen configurations in the above table. Screen size lower than 3 inches is mostly smartwatches and more than 8 inches could be Tabs and smart TVs. So I have taken devices with the screen size between 3 - 8 inches as mobile devices (smartphones).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is easy to do in native android you can create a method and check for the `DensityMetricsDensity` something like below:

```
private string GetDeviceDensity()
    {
        var density = Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi;
        switch (density)
        {
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Medium:
                return "MDPI";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.High:
                return "HDPI";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Low:
                return "LDPI";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xhigh:
                return "XHDPI";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Tv:
                return "TV";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xxhigh:
                return "XXHDPI";
            case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xxxhigh:
                return "XXXHDPI";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You see, in the tested emulator list, 240dpi and 280dpi devices would fall into HDPI bucket. A device with resolution 1280x720 won't cause a problem since it has higher resolution, but 800x480 resolution will.

Comment: 800 x 400 is this device in landscape or potrait?

Comment: all the mentioned devices are portrait.

Comment: Why not just check the display metrics and if it is 800x400 do something different according to the case

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a more general solution.

Comment: The solution above is the only known general solution(if you ask me), if you do find something else let me know